# Anonymous Function Passed as Argument Between Namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, anonymous-function

The following code causes PHP to throw an error:

```
namespace NamespaceOne;

class MyClass {
    function __construct( array $config ) {
        $func = $config['func'];
        $value = 'Hello World';
        echo $func( $value );   // This part throws the error
    }
}
```

The class is instantiated in a different file:

```
namespace NamespaceTwo;

$class = new \NamespaceOne\MyClass( array(
    'func' => function( $v ) { return $v; }
));
```

Terminates with the error:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string [...]
```

**EDIT**

If I re-declare the function inside the namespace, it works:

```
class MyClass {
    function __construct( array $config ) {
        $config['func'] = function( $v ) { return $v; };
        $func = $config['func'];
        $value = 'Hello World';
        echo $func( $value );   // Echos "Hello World"
    }
}
```

So now we know what causes it to break, but how do we pass an anonymous function between namespaces?

Comment: it is fine for me http://3v4l.org/Fbq5g

Comment: remove $ from $func and name it function

Comment: This is *still* working just fine: http://3v4l.org/ki58v

Comment: @deceze sorry, turns out the problem had nothing to do with anonymous functions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

namespace MyNamespace {

```
class MyClass {

    function __construct(array $config) {
        $func = $config['func'];
        $value = 'Hello World';
        echo $func($value);   // This part throws the error
    }

}
```

}